# Redirect https to http without SSL - IIS 7

Tags: redirect, iis, indexing, iis-7, http-status-code-301

I recently moved my website from Wix.com to one that I created on GoDaddy (Windows server).  Wix.com version used https, and the latter doesn't.  Searching for the website on Google still lists the "https://*" version (which doesn't exist anymore) instead of listing the "http://" version.

**Question 1:**
How should I redirect visitors from https to http version without having to set up SSL on the new website? Adding this to web.config didn't help:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
     </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

**Question 2:**
What should I do to make sure Google search shows the http version and not the https version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It is not possible without SSL certificate. You can generate valid free certificate here: https://www.sslforfree.com/, add https into your IIS bindings and then your rule will work

2) In Google webmaster tools they have the option to change the address: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Victor. 1) worked for me. But for 2) - I don't have access to the Wix website (i.e. old, https one) and the property I've added on Google webmaster is of the new website. Change of Address seems to require creating a property for both new and old sites - can't do that for the old one.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Then you can just wait until Google reindex your website again and will remove old https links

Comment: Thank you, Victor!